# Mapped relation in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have been playing with postgresql for a while now and this one caught my eye. What is a "mapped relation" in postgresql. According to the documentation,

> When the name of on-disk file is zero, it is called a "mapped"
>   relation whose disk file name is determined by low - level state.

Is it a simple relation that doesnt have a fixed OID to reference it with. Why is it created? What is its significance?Or is it similar to a temp table?
        can some one thow light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-file-layout.html

> Also, for certain system catalogs including pg_class itself,
>   pg_class.relfilenode contains zero. The actual filenode number of
>   these catalogs is stored in a lower-level data structure, and can be
>   obtained using the pg_relation_filenode() function.

```
t=# select relfilenode from pg_class where relname = 'pg_class';
 relfilenode
-------------
           0
(1 row)

t=# select pg_relation_filenode('pg_class');
 pg_relation_filenode
----------------------
                12712
(1 row)
```

now a little barbarian (yet user friendly) way to make sure it is the file:

```
t=# create table very_special_name(i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# CHECKPOINT; --to actually write to disk
CHECKPOINT
t=# select oid from pg_database where datname='t';
   oid
----------
 13805223
(1 row)
```

so we check the readable strings:

```
-bash-4.2$ strings /pg/data/base/13805223/12712  | grep very_special
very_special_name
```

New table name is in...

Comment: So, only catalog tables are mapped or a user table can also be mapped?

Comment: I'd say so. try `select relname from pg_class where relfilenode = 0` to see if its the case in your db

Comment: Yeah, the results of that query in all my dbs gave only catalog tables. Thanks :)

Comment: The same table has the 2 values for relfilenode, somebody know why?
table1 oid: 24997 relfilenode: 0
table1 oid: 24514 relfilenode: 24514